# Displaying text from a sf::Text object from another Class. SFML

Tags: c++, xcode, sfml

I am trying to create a class that will create a black box with some white text in it. It would eventually be able to scale the size of the box depending on the string that is sent to the class. But, to begin with, I do not know why the text does not display. I appreciate the help.

Here is the TextBox.h

```
class TextBox{

public:

sf::RectangleShape rect;
sf::Text text;
sf::Font font;

TextBox(std::string str, sf::Font f);
sf::Text getText();
```

This is the TextBox Constructor that is found in the TextBox.cpp. The sf::Font I am sending to the constructor is the font that was set by SFML.

```
#include "TextBox.h"
#include "string"

TextBox::TextBox(std::string str, sf::Font font){

rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
rect.setPosition(20, 20);
rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(120,120));

text.setFont(font);
text.setString(str);
text.setCharacterSize(24);
text.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);

text.setPosition(rect.getPosition());

}
```

This is the code in the main.cpp that should be displaying both the Rect and the Text

```
sf::Font font;
if (!font.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "sansation.ttf")) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

TextBox textBox("This Box", font);
textBox.text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
// Start the game loop
while (window.isOpen())
{
    // Process events
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        // Close window: exit
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
            window.close();
        }

        // Escape pressed: exit
        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
            window.close();
        }
    }

    // Clear screen
    window.clear();

    window.draw(textBox.rect);
    window.draw(textBox.text);

    // Update the window
    window.display();
```

I have tried using a public getText() method that returns a sf::Text object, but it does not solve the issue.
Also, the modifications I do for the rect do work and the rect is displayed. The text isn't.

Thank you and Cheers

Comment: Pass the `font` by const reference, dont pass it as a copy: `TextBox::TextBox(std::string str, const sf::Font& font)` https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Text.php#a2927805d1ae92d57f15034ea34756b81

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`sf::Text::setFont()` method](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Text.php#a2927805d1ae92d57f15034ea34756b81):

> The font argument refers to a font that must exist as long as the text uses it. Indeed, the text doesn't store its own copy of the font, but rather keeps a pointer to the one that you passed to this function. If the font is destroyed and the text tries to use it, the behavior is undefined.

.

In your `TextBox` constructor, you pass `font` as a copy `f`, after initialize `textBox`, the font copy `f` will be destroyed, hence your `textBox.text` is not displayed.

Fixing it is simple: pass `font` as it is by using pass by (constant) reference:
`TextBox(std::string str, const sf::Font& f);`

(You might want to pass `std::string` as const reference, too)